# How to change JButton stat in other Class

Tags: java, swing

I have many class.java files and I need to disable / enable a Button by method in other class the button is . 
I have code like this
1st class

```
public class Main {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();

JButton b_X = new JButton("X");

 }
```

2nd class

```
public class GUI extends Main{
Button B = new Button();

GUI(){
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocation(400, 200);

    frame.add(b_X);

    b_X.setBounds(0, 0, 120, 20);

    b_X.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                    B.call();
        update();

        }
    });

}
public int update(){
    //some uniportant code
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new GUI();
}

}
```

3rd class

```
public class Button extends Main{
UserMethods UM = new UserMethods();


public int call(){
    UM.m1();
    //Uniportant stuff..
}

 }
```

last 4th class

```
public class UserMethods extends Main{



public int m0(){
    if(n1 >= n2){
        n1 = 0;
        n2 = n2 + 40;
        n3++;
    }

    return n3;
}

public int m1(){
    //uniportant code again
    if(ASD == 0){
        b_X.setEnabled(false);

    }
    return XYZ;
}

}
```

The code is more complicated and is much larger but that stuff is not important for this problem.

MAIN PROBLEM:

> I need to somehow update button b_X in GUI class from method in last
>   UserMethods class . but when I add line GUI G = new GUI() to the last
>   class and then refer to G.update(); (which updates all the stuff) I
>   create endless loop like Class C refers to C3 ,C3 to C4 and C4 to C2
>   (if I get it right ) and the Java pops up with error StackOverFlow...
>   Is there any help for using method in GUI class from the method in 4th
>   class ?

BTW: Don't mind my style of code , don't mind my english and don't mind anything else. I need help with the main problem not with other stuff.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using static for the first class:

```
public static class Main {

    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static JButton b_X = new JButton("X");

}
```

Then you *should* be able to access it from another class using:

```
Main.b_x.someFunction();
```

Comment: Oh dear god no! What happens if the OP has multiple instances of Main! Static is not a solution for passing references, you should pass references. This is a bad example which will lead the I into bad habits!

Answer (score 0):

You should never directly modify the child components of another object, this will place a lot of strain on your logic as your class compete to enforce there concept of what is the correct state and will place your program into inconsistent state very, very fast

One of the better solutions would be to use some kind model/controller interface. You would create an instance of this model/controller and pass it to the other classes, probably via the constructor.

The model/controller would define what each class was a capable of doing and define means by which could be notified of state changes

Each class would be responsible for determining what that state change means to them and update them selves accordingly

Have a read of [Model-View-Controller](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) for more details. Swing uses these concepts at its core, so an understating them will help you understand the overall API better

Comment: Thanks for yout advice , I've readed the stuff you recomended to me , also something more from that pages , it helped me alot in many ways so I rewriten many parts of my code and now it works perfectly - Thanks alot !